# Google Apps Script — GmailApp.sendMessage advanced option 'name' does not work

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script

According to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_gmailapp#sendEmail, the function

```
function myFunction() {
  GmailApp.sendEmail("address@domain.com", "Foo", "Hello World!", {name:"Fred Freddington"});
}
```

should send an email to `address@domain.com` with the subject `Foo`, message body `Hello World!`, and should appear to be from `Fred Freddington`. Indeed, this is what used to happen, but now it just says it's from the Gmail account the script is associated with. Does anyone know how to get around this and/or why Google have changed this but not updated their documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to [Issue 2004](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2004). Please star the issue to be notified of updates to the issue